# Issue with including data file in a LaTeX table using the tabularray package

Tags: tabularray, pythontex, longtblr

I am facing difficulties in including the contents of an external file into a LaTeX table using the tabularray package. I am using the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
from scipy.constants import physical_constants

constants = physical_constants.keys()

table = []
for constant in constants:
    value, unit, uncertainty = physical_constants[constant]
    table.append([constant, value, unit, uncertainty])

# Função para formatar um valor com unidade
def format_value_with_unit(value, unit):
    formatted_value = r'\num{' + str(value) + r'}'
    formatted_unit = r'\unit{' + unit + r'}'
    return formatted_value, formatted_unit

# Gravar o output em um arquivo LaTeX
with open('output.tex', 'w') as f:
    # f.write(r'\begin{tabular}{cccc}' + '\n')
    f.write(r'\textbf{Constante} & \textbf{Valor} & \textbf{Unidade} & \textbf{Incerteza} \\ \hline' + '\n')
    
    # Escrever as constantes com seus valores e unidades
    for row in table:
        constant = row[0]
        value = row[1]
        unit = row[2]
        uncertainty = row[3]

        formatted_value, formatted_unit = format_value_with_unit(value, unit)

        line = constant + ' & ' + formatted_value + ' & ' + formatted_unit + ' & ' + r'\num{' + str(uncertainty) + r'}' + r' \\'
        f.write(line + '\n')
    
    # f.write(r'\end{tabular}')
\end{pycode}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Constantes da Física.},
label = {constantes},
]{
colspec = {XXXX}, 
width = \linewidth,
}
\input{output.tex}
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

The file output.tex contains a list of constants and their respective values, units, and uncertainties. However, when I compile the code, I receive the following error:

```
(./pythontex-files-stack-overflow/stack-overflow.pytxpyg) (./output.tex
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.1 \textbf{Constante} &
                         \textbf{Valor} & \textbf{Unidade} & \textbf{Incerte...
```

Could someone help me identify what I am doing wrong or provide an alternative solution to include the content of the output.tex file in the table?

I appreciate any help you can offer!

Thank you,
Luís Ferreira

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation of the `tabularray` package, add

```
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}
```

to preamble

and use

```
\begin{longtblr}[
evaluate = \fileInput,
caption = {Constantes da Física.},
label = {constantes},
]{
colspec = {XXXX}, 
width = \linewidth,
}
\fileInput{output}
\end{longtblr}
```

Or, make it so that `output.tex` contains the whole thing, i.e. not only the data but the `longtblr` environment.

Side remark: this gives a 30 pages document whose build time is inordinately long.  If I were in your place I would not use `tabularray` package but some `longtable` with suitable traditional `p` columns with suitably chosen width.  It appears the `tabularray` approach has simply too much overhead on such example.  Except if you have a really fast CPU.  I admit my material is rather antiquated.

Also, the first column "Constante" displays badly.  You can include `\usepackage{ragged2e}` in the document preamble and insert `>{\RaggedRight}` in the table preamble specification to improve things (i.e. if sticking with `tabularray` use `colspec = {>{\RaggedRight}XXXX},`).

##### Update:

I obtained a reasonable result (and a very much faster build, but 2 compilations are needed) with

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{longtable}{>{\RaggedRight}p{2.5cm}SSS}
\input{output}
\end{longtable}
```

Edit: here is more evolved, but the best would be to remove from `output.tex` the header line then

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{longtable}{>{\RaggedRight}p{2.5cm}SSS}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Table of physical constants (cont.)}}\\\hline\noalign{\vskip2\jot}
\endhead
\input{output}
\end{longtable}
```

But you may (should?) consider refinements of this using optional argument of `S` specifier, see `siunitx` documentation (things such as `S[table-column-width = 2cm]`  syntax appears relevant).   Then the whole `\num` and `\unit` mark-up in `output.tex` may be redundant, or not (I am not too familiar with `siunitx`).

##### Side remark

The mark-up in `output.tex` for negative exponents is wrong. And also it is lacking a dot between units. Things such as `\unit{C^4 m^4 J^-3}` should be `\unit{C^4.m^4.J^{-3}}` or `\unit{C^4.m^4/J^3}`.  See `siunitx` documentation section `3.3 Units`.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!
You helped me a lot!