Fill table from pythontex
I want to fill a table with numbers generated by pythontex like in the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[gobble=auto]{pythontex}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}[test]
from numpy import *
def printA(A):
    print(" & ".join(map(str, A)).replace(".",","))

X = arange(0,3,0.5)  
Y = [x**2 for x in X]
\end{pycode}

\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{}    
\(x\) & \pyc[test]{printA(X)} \\
\(y\) & \pyc[test]{printA(Y)} \\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}

The problem is that it gives me multiple "Misplaced alignment tab character &." errors. What did I make wrong and how can I fix it?

Expansion issue, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690094/issue-with-including-data-file-in-a-latex-table-using-the-tabularray-package https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648904/misplaced-alignment-tab-character-with-tabularray-and-expl3 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654206/generate-rows-for-tabularray-with-pyluatex . Good thing tabularray supports functional so you can get away with implementing a PythonTeX wrapper. (also consider reporting as feature request on https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray )

I suggest the idea to lvjr
